# I have major problem and need to save my laptop

Tags: xorg

My brightness was not working, I was trying to find a solution, well it was a bad call. The tutorial for brightness control was that I need to change `xorg.conf`, to add a line. I didn't find `xorg.conf` file in `/etc/X11` and I created with line of code that "Helps".

Well when I restarted pc screen was black (aprox. when login screen needs to show). I cannot access to HDD. I tried to boot Ubuntu Live CD, but it doesn't allow me to delete it I tried `gksu`, `gksudo nautilus`, etc... here comes the tricky part I am not starter and I know something

Problem causing file is ONLY SHOW in regular nautilus (not in `gksu nautilus` nor the Terminal!). Can someone help me how to delete this NOISY file!?

Answer (score 3):

1. Start your computer up and hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key to see the Grub menu. Select the line that says `Recovery Mode` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
2. When Recovery Mode boots, use the arrow keys to select the option that says `fsck` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. When `fsck` finishes, which might take a while, return to the main Recovery Mode menu and select the `Root shell prompt`/`bash` option.
4. At the prompt, type `rm -v /etc/X11/xorg.conf`. Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> to reboot.
5. Your PC should now boot normally.

To fix your brightness issue, you should add the line of code to a new file in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d` named `60-custom.conf` instead.